# Maintaining two states of turtles netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am doing a small university project. In which i have to maintain 2 states of turtles.
1. Disperse
2. Explore
Disperse :
 In dispersion, when at the start all the turtles (20 turtles) are at 0,0 they should disperse from each other. Every turtle has a radius of 2 patches around it, no other turtle should be in that radius. All turtles should go far until they all attain this radius. then other behavior will be called i.e. Explore.

Explore: 
 In explore , they have to explore the world and avoid different types of obstacles. When ever two turtles come close to each other above mentioned radius then state should be changed to disperse.

I have procedures for obstacle avoidance, and move-speed, and all other individual behaviors under Disperse and Explore. But i don't know how to join all this in one simulation.

Comment: Try it, and show us your attempt? Then we can give you some advice. In the absence of any actual code in your question, it's unclear what kind of help anyone can possibly offer you.

Comment: I have some more troubles in my code. Should i upload the model here Or just paste code portion here...???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear that you really need to maintain turtle state, since you will have to repeatedly check for other turtles in any case.  But since you said you wanted that, you can use `turtles-own`.  For example:

```
turtles-own [state]

to setup
  ca
  crt 20
end

to go
  ask turtles [set-state]
  ask turtles [move]
end

to set-state ;;turtle proc
  ifelse (any? other turtles in-radius 2) [
    set state "disperse"
  ] [
    set state "explore"
  ]
end

to move ;;turtle proc
  if (not member? state ["disperse" "explore"]) [
    error "unknown state"
  ]
  if (state = "disperse") [
    disperse
  ]
  if (state = "explore") [
    explore
  ]
end


to disperse ;;turtle proc
  move-to one-of patch-set [neighbors] of neighbors
end

to explore
  move-to one-of neighbors
end
```

Comment: Its working. I have embedded this scenario into my model. Thanks Sir

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [Moore machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine) and Automata, NetLogo works great with those. 
A Moore machine can be seen as a set of 5 elements that interact with each other, in this particular example the *start state(`S0`)* would be Dispersing. In NetLogo you can use the word [run](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#run) that receives a string. You'd had to make a procedure that returns a string (say `"explore"`) by checking the actual state of a turtle.

I made something like that a few months ago. We were trying to make a hunter-prey model for polar bears and seals (or wolves and sheeps) based on Moore Machines.

You can use the example of @Alan of course, I just skimmed through and I believe it was fine.

Here is [my example](http://codetidy.com/4904/#) based on Moore Machine. It's in spanish but the idea is the same.